# What the response of unstable limit cycles look like?

Tags: mathematics, stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

[image]Stable limit cycles generate oscillations, i was wondering what the unstable limit cycles behaviours look like? From the picture in the left, the system shows a stable limit cycle and it generates oscillations as a function of time. What do the unstable limit cycle generates as a function of time?

Any help with this will be appreciated,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A cycle, stable or not, is periodic motion:

- If you are able to, say, analytically, place an initial condition exactly on your unstable cycle, its forward trajectory will be a periodic oscillation just like that of a stable one;
- now, any perturbation, be it numerical or experimental will cause the trajectory to move away from the unstable cycle to a different region of phase space where its behavior will be defined by what it finds there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So basically in the unstable limit cycle, the oscillation is depending on the initial condition. Whereas, in the stable limit cycle, the oscillation does not depend on the initial condition

Comment: @yaya10 Perhaps almost like that - for the stable cycle there is a finite region around it where initial conditions end up in the cycle; while for unstable cycles, such a region has zero 'area'.